# Dart Factory class for creating variables with type

Tags: flutter, dart, types, factory

The problem is the following.
I had a typescript factory class that I attempted to do in Dart:

```
class FactoryClass{

  factory FactoryClass(dynamic types, String className, dynamic defaultValue){
    if(types[className] != null ){
      return types[className](defaultValue);
    }
    else{
      throw Exception("");
    }
  }
}
```

In TS it was used like this:

```
let variable= new FactoryClass([String, Number, etc...], "Number", "42")
```

That in TypeScript would give back a Number type variable with the value 42

However, it's not gonna work in Dart since types have no constructor for this. So I can't do something like

```
final myString = new String("def_value")
```

So the question arises, how can I go about it in dart?

Comment: You could make `types` be a `Map<String, FactoryClass Function(dynamic defaultValue)>`.

Comment: the list `types`, will contain [built-in types](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#built-in-types), or user-defined classes? or a mix of both?  
And do you really have to pass the `className` as a String?

Comment: the types list can contain a mix of both. Yes, className will be a String every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do similar in Dart with just functions:

```dart
typedef Factory = dynamic Function(dynamic value);

dynamic create(Map<String, Factory> types, String className, dynamic defaultValue) {
    if (types.containsKey(className)) {
      return types[className]!(defaultValue);
    } else {
      throw Exception("no factory for $className");
    }
  }

final factories = <String,  Factory>{
  'String': (s) => s.toString(),
  'int': (i) => i is int ? i : int.parse('$i'),
  'bool': (b) => b is bool ? b : ('$b' == 'true'),
};

show(v) => print('Value $v has type ${v.runtimeType}');

main() {
  show(create(factories, 'String', 'foo'));
  show(create(factories, 'int', '42'));
  show(create(factories, 'bool', 'false'));
}
```

Prints:

```
Value foo has type String
Value 42 has type int
Value false has type bool
```

Comment: This solution seems to be the closest to what I'm trying to achieve, however I need to explicitly define how to do the conversion in the factories Map. 

If there won't be anything better, I will accept this as an answer, thank you

Comment: Difficult to know what exactly you need given the available information. I can't see how you cannot achieve what you want based on this. If you explain the exact problem you see maybe I can suggest something more.